# API Hooking which takes effect across entire process - both EXE and DLLs

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I have an application consists of a single EXE and multiple DLLs. After reading [Windows via C/C++](http://www.wintellect.com/books.aspx), I try to perform hook on `Sleep` function in one of the DLL, and expecting the hook will work across both EXE and all DLLs. Note that, `CAPIHook` code is getting from [Windows via C/C++'s sample code](http://www.wintellect.com/Downloads/Windows%20via%20C++%20Code%20%28December%201,%202007%29.zip)

**In DLL Project**

```
void WINAPI MySleep( DWORD dwMilliseconds );
CAPIHook g_Sleep("Kernel32.dll", "Sleep", (PROC)MySleep);
typedef void (WINAPI *Sleep_Type)( DWORD dwMilliseconds );

// Hook function.
void WINAPI MySleep( DWORD dwMilliseconds )
{
    printf ("-------> In MySleep\n");
    ((Sleep_Type)(PROC)g_Sleep)(dwMilliseconds);

}

// This is an example of an exported function.
DLL_API int dll_function_which_is_going_to_call_sleep(void)
{
    printf ("DLL function being called\n");
    printf ("Call Sleep in DLL function\n");
    Sleep(100);

    return 42;
}
```

**In EXE Project**

```
void CexeDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    printf ("Button being clicked\n");

    printf ("Call Sleep in EXE function\n");
    Sleep(100);

    dll_function_which_is_going_to_call_sleep();

    printf ("Call Sleep in EXE function\n");
    Sleep(100);

    dll_function_which_is_going_to_call_sleep();
}
```

This is the output I am getting

```
Button being clicked
Call Sleep in EXE function
-------> In MySleep
DLL function being called
Call Sleep in DLL function
Call Sleep in EXE function
-------> In MySleep
DLL function being called
Call Sleep in DLL function
```

**What make me feel strange is that, I am expecting `CAPIHook` will take effect across entire single process. Since EXE and DLLs belong to a same process, both should be able to reach `MySleep`**. However, my observation is that, only call from EXE will reach `MySleep`, but not DLL.

I locate sample code right here [CAPIHook-doesnt-have-effect-in-entire-process.zip](https://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/CAPIHook-doesnt-have-effect-in-entire-process.zip), it contains `dll` and `exe` projects.

I also once drop in replace `CHookAPI` with code in [apihijack](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/apihijack.aspx). Same problem still happen. The hooking effect will not spread across entire process.

Is there anything I had missed out? Please do not suggest me to use EasyHook, Detours, ..., as I just want to know why the above code won't work, and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the original **CAPIHook** does not replace local IAT (in your case, the DLL project which contains binaries for CAPIHook).

The reason behind this was to protect itself from infinite recursion which lead to *stackoverflow* (which the users will also post question in SO :D).

To ensure that any subsequent modules loaded will be importing the ***"correct"*** function,
CAPIHook search and re-direct *LoadLibrary* and *GetProcAddress* upon construction.

However, these function are used by CAPIHook itself too, so changing local IAT to proxy function (CAPIHook::LoadLibrary or CAPIHook::GetProcAddress) will cause infinite recursion as the proxies unintentionally called itself while trying to call underlying OS API !

One way to solve this is by modifying CAPIHook to check whether it is alright to replace local IAT.

**1.) New attribute m_bIncludeLocalIAT added to CAPIHook and ctor/dtor modified accordingly.**

```
class CAPIHook
{
...
CAPIHook(PSTR pszCalleeModName, PSTR pszFuncName, 
         PROC pfnHook, BOOL bIncludeLocalIAT = TRUE);
...
BOOL m_bIncludeLocalIAT;
...
};


CAPIHook::CAPIHook( PSTR pszCalleeModName, PSTR pszFuncName, 
                    PROC pfnHook, BOOL bIncludeLocalIAT) {
    ...
    m_bIncludeLocalIAT = bIncludeLocalIAT;
    ...
    ReplaceIATEntryInAllMods(m_pszCalleeModName, m_pfnOrig, m_pfnHook, m_bIncludeLocalIAT);
}

CAPIHook::~CAPIHook() {
    ReplaceIATEntryInAllMods(m_pszCalleeModName, m_pfnHook, m_pfnOrig, m_bIncludeLocalIAT);
    ...
}
```

**2.) New parameter added to the static function *CAPIHook::ReplaceIATEntryInAllMods*.**

```
static void WINAPI ReplaceIATEntryInAllMods(PCSTR pszCalleeModName, 
      PROC pfnOrig, PROC pfnHook, BOOL bReplaceLocalIAT){

   HMODULE hmodThisMod = ExcludeAPIHookMod 
      ? ModuleFromAddress(ReplaceIATEntryInAllMods) : NULL;

   // Get the list of modules in this process
   CToolhelp th(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, GetCurrentProcessId());

   MODULEENTRY32 me = { sizeof(me) };
   for (BOOL bOk = th.ModuleFirst(&me); bOk; bOk = th.ModuleNext(&me)) {

      if (bReplaceLocalIAT || (me.hModule != hmodThisMod)) {

         // Hook this function in this module
         ReplaceIATEntryInOneMod(
            pszCalleeModName, pfnCurrent, pfnNew, me.hModule);
      }
   }
}
```

**3.) Update the static CAPIHook instances**

```
CAPIHook CAPIHook::sm_LoadLibraryA  ("Kernel32.dll", "LoadLibraryA",   
   (PROC) CAPIHook::LoadLibraryA, FALSE);

CAPIHook CAPIHook::sm_LoadLibraryW  ("Kernel32.dll", "LoadLibraryW",   
   (PROC) CAPIHook::LoadLibraryW, FALSE);

CAPIHook CAPIHook::sm_LoadLibraryExA("Kernel32.dll", "LoadLibraryExA", 
   (PROC) CAPIHook::LoadLibraryExA, FALSE);

CAPIHook CAPIHook::sm_LoadLibraryExW("Kernel32.dll", "LoadLibraryExW", 
   (PROC) CAPIHook::LoadLibraryExW, FALSE);

CAPIHook CAPIHook::sm_GetProcAddress("Kernel32.dll", "GetProcAddress", 
   (PROC) CAPIHook::GetProcAddress, FALSE);
```

Comment: A very useful explanation on why it is not working. Thumb up!